# Output from Photoshop API to signed URL on S3 fails with 403 Access is forbidden error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-nodejs, photoshop-sdk

When I am using the [AIO library](https://github.com/adobe/aio-lib-photoshop-api) and I try to create a rendition using the createRendition call I am getting the following error:

```
{
  code: 403,
  details: [
    {
      name: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/...',
      reason: 'Unable to upload the outputs'
    }
  ],
  title: 'Access Is Forbidden',
  type: 'AuthForbidden'
}
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```ts
const util = require('util');
const stream = require('stream');
const pipeline = util.promisify(stream.pipeline);
const sdk = require('@adobe/aio-lib-photoshop-api');

function createRenditionOfPSD() {

      // GENERATE A NEW TOKEN
      const authDetails: string = await this.generateIMSToken(clientIdAndApiKey, clientSecret);
      let authInfo = JSON.parse(authDetails);
      authToken = authInfo.access_token;

      // CREATE PS API OBJECT
      const client = await sdk.init(ims, clientIdAndApiKey, authToken);

      // GET SIGNED URL
      var signedPSDGetURL = await getSignedUrl(key, bucket);

      // CREATE SIGNED URL FOR SAVING THE OUTPUT
      var psdImageKey = id + ".png";
      //var signedOutputURL = await getSignedPutUrl(psdImageKey, bucket);
      var signedOutputURL = await getSignedPostUrl(psdImageKey, bucket);

      // CREATE DOCUMENT RENDITION
      var psdInputOptions = {
        href: signedPSDGetURL,
        storage: sdk.Storage.EXTERNAL
      }
 
      var psdOutputOptions = {
        href: signedOutputURL,
        type: sdk.MimeType.PNG,
        storage: sdk.Storage.EXTERNAL,
        overwrite: true
      }

      const renditionResults = await client.createRendition(psdInputOptions, psdOutputOptions);
      console.log(renditionResults);

      var outputs = psdRenditionResults.outputs;

      for (var output in outputs) {
        var outputItem = outputs[output];
        var status = outputItem.status;

        if (status=="failed") {
          var errors = outputItem.errors;
          console.log(errors);
        }
        log(output)
      }
}
```

The results:

```
Job {
  getJobStatus: [Function: bound __getJobStatus] AsyncFunction,
  url: 'https://image.adobe.io/pie/psdService/status/....',
  jobId: '...',
  outputs: [
    {
      input: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/...',
      status: 'failed',
      created: '...',
      modified: '...',
      errors: [Object]
    }
  ],
  _links: {
    self: {
      href: 'https://image.adobe.io/pie/psdService/status/...'
    }
  }
}
```

The get signed PUT url and get signed Post URL functions are below:

```ts
export async function getSignedPutUrl(
  key: string,
  bucket: string,
  expireAfterMinutes: number = 0,
  options = null,
): Promise<string> {
  const s3 = new AWS.S3();
  var params = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: key,
  };

  if (options) {
    params = Object.assign(params, options);
  }

  const url = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise("putObject", params);
  return url;
}

export async function getSignedPostUrl(
  key: string,
  bucket: string,
  expireAfterMinutes: number = 0,
  options = null,
): Promise<string> {
  const s3 = new AWS.S3();
  var params = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Fields: {
      Key: key,
      ContentType: "application/octet-stream",
    },
  };

  if (options) {
    params = Object.assign(params, options);
  }

  const presignedPost = await s3.createPresignedPost(params);
  const url = presignedPost.url;
  return url;
}
```

I've tried creating a PUT URL and a POST URL, removed the ContentType and so far nothing has worked. Is there something I'm missing?

Creating a [presigned](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createPresignedPost-property) post URL.

**UPDATE**:

Found more info on the storage [types](https://developer.adobe.com/photoshop/photoshop-api-docs/general-workflow/#input-and-output-file-storage). The page says for saving the output it's a PUT URL but this [example code](https://developer.adobe.com/photoshop/photoshop-api-docs/code-sample/#create-a-document-rendition) for `createRendition` says POST URL but the other [example page](https://developer.adobe.com/photoshop/photoshop-api-docs/api/#tag/Photoshop/operation/renditionCreate) says PUT url. Will update and see. There's example S3 [code](https://github.com/AdobeDocs/cis-photoshop-api-docs/blob/main/sample-code/storage-app/aws-s3/presignedURLs.js). I've got it to save. The save status is not "failed". But having issues with getting the url returned. I probably have to sign it.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: In your `psdOutputOptions` you've got `href: signedPutURL`. Did you mean `href: signedOutputURL`?

Comment: Typo? `Key: key` should be lowercase `key: key` (typically just written `key`) in `params` if I read the createPresignedPost docs correctly.

Comment: @Phil i added the `createRenditionOfPSD` in this post. it's named something else. i'll update it to add `function`

Comment: @Phil yes it's a typo but the actual code uses signed output url

Comment: @jarmod that's true. the documentation uses the lowercase "key" but others have posted examples with uppercase "Key" and other examples seem to follow this format. I'll try both and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: It's definitely `key` (lowercase). You can see it here ~ https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createPresignedPost-property

Comment: If aws is listening, the error messages suck. I've been working on this a week

Comment: @Phil i used lower case and i'm still getting the same error. glad aws gives such helpful error messages that isn't vague and useless

Comment: By the way, the error messages you've shown ("Unable to upload the outputs" and 'AuthForbidden') do not appear to be AWS-generated messages. AWS, for example, would respond 403 (Forbidden) with AccessDenied, not AuthForbidden.

Comment: @jarmod then that may be PS API responding to 403 error. Here is the documentation https://developer.adobe.com/photoshop/photoshop-api-docs/api/#tag/Photoshop/operation/renditionCreate

Comment: @phil you don't need to write `function` in front of class methods

Comment: @1.21gigawatts it's not clear from your question that it is a class method.

Comment: @jarmod I'd say the Photoshop service tries to upload the file to the provided pre-signed URL and receives a 403 from AWS, ignores the actual message and sends it's own 403 status and message back

Comment: @Phil that might be. i've posted on their forums

Comment: This might help ~ [Getting 403 (Forbidden) when uploading to S3 with a signed URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46869962/283366). You need to configure the pre-signing fields to exactly match those that the Photoshop service will request. This would be things like request header values. You might be able to get more details about the problem from CloudWatch ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Phil yeah that's what it sounds like. I don't know what the PS API is sending to that signed URL. I don't know the headers, the form values, the method (put or post), etc. And none of their documentation I've seen provides that info.

Answer (score 0):

To save the output requires an exact match of the signed URL to the service and the service sending the exact form to that URL.

There is no way to get that exact match from trial and error. There was a slightly misleading code example but the same page linked to the documentation that has example code for s3 [here](https://developer.adobe.com/photoshop/photoshop-api-docs/general-workflow/#input-and-output-file-storage).

Here is the basic get put url function using async (but check their documentation):

```
export async function getSignedPutUrl(key: string, bucket: string):Promise<string>{
    const s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01', signatureVersion: 'v4'});

    var params = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: key,
        Expires: 3600 * 24
    };

    const url = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('putObject', params);
    return url;
}
```